# What is the position of neutral point when a bar magnet is placed facing N-pole eastward?

Tags: magnetic-fields

when a bar magnet is place N-pole facing geographical North, the neutral point is obtained on axial line. Where will be the neutral point when it is rotated so that N-pole faces geographical east?

Comment: Are you looking for an exact mathematical solution or just a visual giving the idea?

Comment: @mikuszefski  visual idea will also help me right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the exact position you have, of course, to solve:

$$H_x=-\frac P r^3 +3 \frac{P x^2}{r^5}=0$$
$$H_y= 3 \frac{P x y}{r^5} -H_0=0$$
The equation for $H_x$ is easy and gives you $y = \pm \sqrt 2 x$. The second, I think, needs to be solved numerically. Putting it as implicit plot over the stream lines of the field looks like:
[image: Unit plot]

where I've chosen $P=1$ and $H_0=1$. You see that the two plots (the straight line and the 8-shaped implicit plot) cross where the streamlines show the neutral point.